# index of tr with tds only  --- relative to click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the index of the `<tr>` in the table but only if it has `<td>s` and not `<th>s`

If I use  a click event below  it will alert the index of the  with `td` and `th`   but I only want `<tr>` with `<td>s`

thanks

```
$('td').click(function(){


   var s = $(this).parents('table tr:has(td)').index();//////  returns 

   alert(s);

});




<table>
<tr>
<th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('td').click(function(){
   if ( ! $(this).closest('table').find('th').length ) {
       var s = $(this).closest('tr').index();
       alert(parseInt(s) + 1);
   }
});​
```

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/XkTvt/2/)**

Comment: thanks - but it returns the same as mine  - if I click on the first <td> row then it must show (1) but it must show zero as it is the first in the index -- is this possible?

Comment: Yes thats pretty simple. Index is always zero based just add one to it that will do... I'm modifying my code...

Comment: is there an easier way with out adding and subtracting zeros? Thank for the help.

Comment: Sorry I do not have any idea about that. This is what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your given code is working properly. see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5uNt/).

Comment: thanks but Its not brining back the zero index of the tr with tds only its including the th

Comment: thanks - but if I click on the first td it brings back 1 not zero? the quick fix is to subtract 1 but I was hoping to filter with jquery? Is this possible?

Comment: Hi thanks - but the only the first tr with tds  must show index zero. thanks for the help